# WebView GetHitTestResult() shows previous node when simulating mouse clicks

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview, motionevent

I need to simulate clicking on nodes in HTML pages inside an Android WebView, then log which node was clicked. However, when I call `GetHitTestResult` from `OnTouchEvent` in my subclassed WebView, instead of showing the node that was just clicked on, it shows the node that had been clicked on just *before* this click.  (i.e.: Start out with an edit node selected, then fake-click on Image1.png, and `GetHitTestResult` in `OnTouchEvent` shows the original edit node rather than "Image1". If you then click on Image2.png, `GetHitTestResult` shows "Image1". Then click on something else and it shows "Image2".)

Actual mouse clicks show the correct node -- it is just via my simulated clicks that `GetHitTestResult` shows the wrong node.  (On actual mouse clicks, the "Down" event shows the previous node but the "Up" event shows the current/correct node.)  Unfortunately, I don't have any control over most of the web pages, so I can only do the node detection from my logging code.

Do I need to call something between the simulated "Down" click and the simulated "Up" click for the node change to be recognized by Android / Xamarin / the WebView widget? (BTW: This is in Xamarin.Android.)  Or is there any way in Android to force it to process any outstanding `DispatchTouchEvent` events that might still be pending in the UI thread? (Perhaps the problem is caused by something that hasn't been processed between the fake "Down" click and the fake "Up" click?)

C# Clicking code:

```
void ClickThePage(WebView webView, float left, float top) {

    long downTime = Android.OS.SystemClock.UptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = Android.OS.SystemClock.UptimeMillis() + 100;
    MotionEvent motionEventDown = MotionEvent.Obtain(
        downTime, eventTime, MotionEventActions.Down,
        left, top, (MetaKeyStates)0x0
    );

    downTime = Android.OS.SystemClock.UptimeMillis() + 200;
    eventTime = Android.OS.SystemClock.UptimeMillis() + 300;
    MotionEvent motionEventUp = MotionEvent.Obtain(
        downTime, eventTime, MotionEventActions.Down,
        left, top, (MetaKeyStates)0x0
    );

    // actually do the "Click"
    webView.DispatchTouchEvent (motionEventDown);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (50);
    webView.DispatchTouchEvent (motionEventUp);

    motionEventDown.Recycle ();
    motionEventUp.Recycle ();
}
```

Click-capturing code:

```
public class SAWebView : WebView {
    ...
    public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e) {
        Console.WriteLine("[SAWebView]: OnTouchEvent: Action = " + e.Action + 
            "\n HitTestResult.Type = " + GetHitTestResult().Type +
            "\n HitTestResult.Extra = " + GetHitTestResult().Extra);
        return base.OnTouchEvent (e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm currently stuck with the very sam problem